# Speed Up Numpy Process Across Multiple Arrays in Parallel

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, numpy-ndarray

I have constructed a script to find the 8 nearest indices at the current index in a loop; in essence a moving window algorithm. The parallel component entails doing this across multiple 2-D arrays, which may vary in total amount but will always have the same dimensions (say 2800i x 1200j). I've tested this script below with 12, all arrays have a datatype of Float32 with a maximum decimal precision of 8.

First, let's start with the nearest neighbor portion of the script, which is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mpr

def get_neighbors(arr, origin, num_neighbors = 8):
    coords = np.array([[i,j] for (i,j),value in np.ndenumerate(arr)]).reshape(arr.shape + (2,))
    distances = np.linalg.norm(coords - origin, axis = -1)
    neighbor_limit = np.sort(distances.ravel())[num_neighbors]

    window = np.where(distances <= neighbor_limit)
    exclude_window = np.where(distances > neighbor_limit)
    
    return window, exclude_window, distances
```

I've built a static array (named `gridranger`) that handles the moving window index loop and is used to provide the window index coordinates for all other 2-D arrays given all others are identical in size.
The goal of this script is to extract all values at the indices in the moving window across all arrays into a list, then perform some analysis. This portion looks as follows; note that the variable `grids` contains the names of all variables mapped to each corresponding 2-D array:

```
def extractor(queue, gridin, windowin):
    extract_values = []
    for i in range(0, len(windowin[0])):
        extract_values.append(gridin[windowin[0][i], windowin[1][i]])
    queue.put(extract_values)

def parallel():
    for index, val in np.ndenumerate(gridranger):
        window, exclude, distances = get_neighbors(gridranger, [index[0], index[1]])
        outarr = np.column_stack((window[0], window[1]))
        outvalues, processes = [], []
        q = mpr.Queue()
        for grid in grids:
            pro = mpr.Process(target=extractor, args=(q, grid, window))
            processes.extend([pro])
            pro.start()
        for p in processes:
            extract_values = q.get()
            outvalues.append(extract_values)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()
#       return outvalues
        print(index, outvalues)
```

The issue I've encountered is the length of time to run this using Multiprocess, which averages at ~7.5-8.5 seconds. This clearly is wholly inefficient for large 2-D arrays like what I'm running this moving window through. What steps can I take to drastically reduce this runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to the parallelization, but your `get_neighbors` function is doing an incredible amount of unnecessary work. Each time you create a new coordinate array, do a full sort of the distances from the origin, and run through the array twice for the include and exclude indices. The following function still repeats some work---the call to ogrid, for example, could be moved outside the function---but it knocks the runtime down by a factor of about 100

```
def get_neighbors_vectorized(arr, origin, num_neighbors = 8):
    n, m = arr.shape 
    # make the coordinates as  a (1,n) shaped array and an (m,) shaped array
    xcoord, ycoord = np.ogrid[0:n, 0:m]
    # the squared distances from the origin are broadcast together by the +
    distances = np.sqrt((xcoord - origin[0])**2 + (ycoord - origin[1])**2)
    # argpartition returns an array where arr[1...k] are the indices of the first k sorted values. This replaces the sort and where calls in your original function
    partition = np.argpartition(distances, num_neighbors, axis=None)
    # convert from the raveled array indices back to 2d
    window = (partition[:num_neighbors] // m, partition[:num_neighbors] % m)
    # only the window itself seems to be used in the subsequent functions
    return window
```

Benchmarking in ipython3

```
In [2]: arr = np.arange(20000).reshape(200, 100)

In [3]: %timeit get_neighbors(arr, [12, 4])
7.36 ms ± 7.14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit get_neighbors_vectorized(arr, [12, 4])
89.2 µs ± 64.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

I don't know what the final purpose of the routines are, but it looks like you're just doing a moving window of some sort, which means that you can probably replace `get_neighbors` entirely.

Comment: I actually discovered that slowdown a mere 12 hours prior, your vectorized nearest neighbor function is significantly faster! I appreciate the code here to speed it up, what would you recommend (unless it's your code above) to replace get_neighbors if I wanted to do a moving window across these arrays?

Comment: depends on what you're actually doing. I'd recommend rewriting what you've got without the parallelization. (`parallel` and `extractor` look like spaghetti code to me rather than anything useful, and there's a lot of inefficient `for` loops in there anyways. 2,000,000 datapoints shouldn't exactly be a heavy lift for modern computers)

Comment: I've followed your suggestion on removing the for loops since this post was written, which has helped performance. My goal here is to apply this nearest neighbor function to get an array of i,j points for each point p in the initial array, then assemble these sub-arrays as one large ndarray to reference. Would np.vectorize or a map function allow me to apply this function to all points at once without executing np.ndenumerate?

Comment: l mean, it's on a regular cartesian grid, isn't it? (if not l hate to tell you, but the code as written is wrong). For every point `(i,j)` you know that its nearest neighbors are `[(i-1, j-1), (i-1, j), (i-1, j+1), (i, j-1), (i, j+1), (i+1, j-1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j+1)]`. If you're just adding or subtracting values at gridpoints at the end, your functions are _already_ vectorized. You just have to worry about what's happening at the boundaries.